# google script array map function transversing output

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have an array of numerical values in a google sheet that all need to have the sign changed on them using app script. For example, 6000 becomes -6000 and so on down the line. I am trying to use an array map function to do this.

When I complete the script, it seems to have transversed the array. My one column and multiple rows has become one row and multiple columns. I've tried so many different examples on this site and I can't seem to make them work. I am new to this, so arrays still seem confusing.

For now, I have simplified and I am testing this on a known (and fixed) range. I'll add the flexibility to the ranges once I can solve the transversion problem.

```
    function changesign() {
      const test_sht = monthly_expense.getSheetByName("Test");
      var sample1 = test_sht.getRange("B2:B6");
      var values1 = sample1.getValues();
      Logger.log(values1);


      var newValues = values1.map(function(value) {
      return value * -1;
      });
      Logger.log(newValues);
      test_sht.getRange("G1:G5").setValues([newValues]); 
    }
```

Result from logger:
10:49:13 PM Info    [[6000.0], [6000.0], [7000.0], [525.0], [23.93]]
10:49:13 PM Info    [-6000.0, -6000.0, -7000.0, -525.0, -23.93]
10:49:13 PM Error   Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values1` is an array of arrays.

So in map(...), each time, `value` is an array that you multiply by -1. Yes, JS is a weird language that lets you multiply an array by a number and gives a number as result... That's why you get returned a number, instead of an array with a number in it.

Let's do it right:

`return [ value[0] * -1 ];`

First, we unwrap the number, then multiply it by -1 and wrap it back in a new array. In the returning result we have an array containing negative number. Then, after map(...) did its job on each value, it returns a new array of arrays `newValues`.

Comment: I figured it was something simple. Very quick and easy fix. Thanks. REVES.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set a column of data (G1 to G5), but the values you're trying to set are in the form of populating a row of data. The `.setValues()` method takes an array in the shape of `values[row][column]` (you're trying to set it as if it accepts an array in the shape of `values[column][row]`, so things get misaligned with the range you've specified)

Instead, you should use a nested `.map()` to create a 2D array in the below shape, which will populate the column:

```js
[
// v-- column
  [-6000.0], // row
  [-6000.0], // row
  [-7000.0], // row
  [-525.0],  // row
  [-23.93]   // row
]
```

Here's how the double-map would look:

```
var newValues = values1.map(function(row) {
  return row.map(function(value) {return value * -1;});
});

test_sht.getRange("G1:G5").setValues(newValues); // set the newly mapped values (not `[newValues]` wrapped in an array).
```

Comment: This answer worked as well as REVES answer below, it was just more difficult for me to follow. Thanks Nick.

Comment: @Andy No worries - Just keep in mind that REVES answer will only work if you've selected a single column of data, if your original selection covers multiple columns then you'll find that theirs will remove the additional columns selected and only flip the sign of the numbers in the first column (whereas this solution will flip the sign of all numbers in the selection, across all rows/columns specified).

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Fortunately, in this case it is just one column.

Answer (score 0):

In the event you may have non numbers

```
function changesign() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var vs = sh.getRange("B2:B6").getValues().flat().map(c => [!isNaN(c) ? -c : c]);
  sh.getRange("B2:B6").setValues(vs);
}
```